# In a subset of a metric space $x$ is in the closure iff there exists a sequence in the subset that converges to $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $A\subseteq X$, denote the closure of $A$ by $\overline{A}$, then $x\in\overline{A}$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)\in A$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$.

*Proof attempt:* ($\rightarrow$) Let $x\in\overline{A}$, then for all $r>0$ the open ball $B(x,r)\cap A\ne\varnothing$. Thus there is an $x_1\in B(x,1)\cap A$, and also an $x_2\in B(x,1/2)\cap A$, and in general for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ we have an $x_n\in B(x,1/n)\cap A$. So consider the sequence $(x_n)=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ composed by all the terms that we know exist in $B(x,1/n)\cap A, n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Now we show that $x_n\rightarrow x$. Let $r>0$, thus by the Archimedean Property there is an $n_0$ such that $1/n_0<r$. Note that $n_0$ has associated an $x_{n_0}$ so that $x_{n_0}\in B(x,1/n_0)\cap A$, i.e., $d(x_{n_0},x)<1/n_0<r$, and for any $n\ge n_0$: $d(x_n,x)<1/n\le1/n_0<r$, therefore $x_n\rightarrow x$.

($\leftarrow$) Suppose $(x_n)\in A$ is a sequence and $x_n\rightarrow x$. Let $r>0$, by the definition of convergence then $x\in A$, thus $B(x,r)\cap A\ne\varnothing$. Therefore $x\in\overline{A}$.

Is this proof correct? I'm not positive of the ($\rightarrow$) part since the rule of assignment of the $x_n$ feels sort of artificial. And the ($\leftarrow$) looks somewhat too easy. I'd be very glad to read your comments on the proof.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks fine, in both directions. As you may be observing, there is a *lot* of slack in how you choose $x_n$.